# Difference between $\mathbb E^x[X_t]$ and $\mathbb E[X_t\mid X_0=x]$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let denote $\mathbb P^x\{X_t\in A\}=\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_0=x\}$ and $\mathbb E^x$ the expectation associated to this measure, i.e. $$\mathbb E^x[X_t]=\int X_t\,\mathrm d \mathbb P^x.$$

I was wondering when $$\mathbb E^x[X_t]=\mathbb E[X_t\mid X_0=x],$$
is valid. In other word, when $$\mathbb E^{X_0}[X_t]=\mathbb E[X_t\mid X_0].$$

For example, if $X_t$ are caracteristic function (i.e. $X_t=\boldsymbol 1_{A_t}$ for measurable sets $A_t$, it hold. But how is it in general ?

Comment: It's a bad idea to define $\mathbb{P}^x$ this way. For instance if $(X_t)_t$ is a one-dimensional Brownian motion, then $\{X_0=x\}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-null set for any $x \neq 0$ and therefore (according to your definition) $\mathbb{P}^x(X_t \in A)=0$ for all $A$ and any $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @saz: I don't really get your comment. Isn't it the way it's defined usually ? (at least in the book of Oksendal : stochastic differential equation)

Comment: @saz: In fact, it looks like $\mathbb P\{X_0=x\}=1$. $(X_t)$ is the unique solution of $dX_t=f(X_t,t)dt+g(X_t,t)dB_t$ where $X_0=x$. Does it makes more sense ?

Comment: No, it's not the usual definition. And no, still doesn't make sense. Why should $\mathbb{P}(X_0=x)=1$? If this was true, you would have $\mathbb{P}^x(X_t \in A) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in A)$...

Comment: @saz: Sorry I don't understand. Notice that they also use this notation in the book you recommanded me once : Brownian motion by Schilling and Partzsch. They say that $\mathbb P^x$ is the law of the Brownian motion starting at $x$. Doesn't it mean that $\mathbb P\{B_0=x\}$ ? May be you could enlighten me on this point ? (and an other time, many thanks for all your very helpful answer).

Comment: There are many books which use the notation $\mathbb{P}^x$ but they do not define it the way you do. Take a Brownian motion $(X_t)_t$ (starting at $X_0 =0$) on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ then, acccording to your definition, it holds that $\mathbb{P}^x(X_t \in A)=0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and all sets $A$. This shows that the definition from your question is quite useless. For Brownian motion $\mathbb{P}^x$ can be defined by the relation $\mathbb{P}^x(X_t \in A) := \mathbb{P}(x+X_t \in A)$.

Comment: @saz: So what would be your definition of $\mathbb P^x$ (for a stochastic process that is not a brownian motion) ?

Comment: Typically this notation is used for Markov processes and then $\mathbb{P}^x$ can be e.g. introduced via the associated semigroup. (Kind of depends on how you define Markov processes, that is, whether you start from the analytical object (i.e. the semigroup) or the probabilistic object (i.e. the stochastic process))